# Stop watch app using service and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I am working on a program that is kind of like a stop watch, that notifies a user to different things. They need to be able to use other apps while waiting for the notification. The notification will be text to speech. If the UI screen is open it needs to see how much time is left, and be able to pause the timer.

I am thinking of using a service for the timer and notification. The service will update the UI through intents and BroadcastReceiver. That means I will have to send a broadcast every second for the time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

A second is a second is a second. Time does not flow faster in one component of your application than another. Hence, you do not need to "send a broadcast every second for the time".

Also, keeping a service in memory that is doing nothing but counting time is a waste of CPU and RAM, the kind of thing that causes users to spew profanity at Android developers while reaching for their favorite task killer.

Use `AlarmManager` to [send an ordered broadcast](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) when the countdown is scheduled to end to handle your `Notification` (and, optionally, doing something directly in your activity). Also store the countdown end time in a persistent store (database, flat file, etc.), and the activity can use that when it comes back on screen to pick up the countdown. If the user pauses the countdown, cancel the outstanding alarm. If the user sets/re-enables the countdown, set the alarm.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation and for the link to the blog post. There it's mentioned that the sample code that demonstrates this concept might be published to your GitHub repo at some point. (The Google Group mentioned seems not to be active anymore.) Was wondering where (and if) I might get the sample code to better understand how all this fits together.

Comment: @aLearner: Here you go: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Ordered